# JSON output in UI using Wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress

Trying to get all posts related to current post category in wordpress.

```
global $post;
$postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
$postcatjson = json_encode( $postcat );
```

from the above codes i am getting output in array, Below, I have mentioned the array.

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(WP_Term)#882 (16) { ["term_id"]=> int(4) ["name"]=> string(6) "Second" ["slug"]=> string(6) "second" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(4) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "category" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(1) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" ["cat_ID"]=> int(4) ["category_count"]=> int(1) ["category_description"]=> string(0) "" ["cat_name"]=> string(6) "Second" ["category_nicename"]=> string(6) "second" ["category_parent"]=> int(0) } }
```

After encoding the above array using

```
$postcatjson = json_encode( $postcat );
```

The JSON output is as follows :

```
[{"term_id":4,"name":"Second","slug":"second","term_group":0,"term_taxonomy_id":4,"taxonomy":"category","description":"","parent":0,"count":1,"filter":"raw","cat_ID":4,"category_count":1,"category_description":"","cat_name":"Second","category_nicename":"second","category_parent":0}]
```

I need to extract cat_ID (The 11th element in the above mentioned JSON)

Comment: the question is not clear, the following JSON string extract by what? it is javascript/ jquery/angular or php. please provide the extract code.

Comment: I want to print "cat_ID (The 11th element in the above mentioned JSON)" using php

Comment: ok then, store the JSON string in a variable like $a and then $b = json_decode($a, true); echo $b[0]['cat_ID']; the output will be 4

Comment: please tell me is it work or not. if you need code help then knock me.

Comment: @Jayanta It works, Please add it to the answer, so that I can accept it and make the question useful for someone else. Thanks

Comment: just wait for few moments sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may help you. after the line **$postcatjson = json_encode( $postcat );**

You just add the line bellow:

```
$decode  = json_decode($postcatjson, true);
echo $decode[0]['cat_ID'];
```